How to overwrite when CloudKit CoreData is synced
Swift UIKit
I'm using CoreData CloudKit.
I want to overwrite values ​​instead of merging them when syncing.
I have the following data:
CloudKit Data (smartphone A)
memo:"123"
In-app data (smartphone B)
memo:"hello"
After syncing with iCloud is complete, memo:"123",memo:"hello" are displayed in the app.
Expected value: memo:"123" (cloudkit data)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
